# Exporting edited dialog.xml to CQ using Brackes

Tags: aem, adobe-brackets

I'm using the Adobe Brackets with the AEM Brackets Extension to edit CQ components, but after editing a **dialog.xml** and exporting it with AEM Brackets Extension, the changes do not appear at CRXDE.

My workflow was:

1. Create the dialog using the CRXDE and saving it;
2. Import the CRXDE data using the AEM Brackets Extension;
3. Edit the imported dialog.xml with Brackets;
4. Export the dialog.xml back to CRXDE.

Here is my edited dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Tab 1">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <title
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Enter title here"
                        name="./title"
                        xtype="textfield"/>
                    <text
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Enter text here"
                        name="./text"
                        xtype="textarea"/>
                    <columns
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Enter number of columns here"
                        name="./columns"
                        xtype="textfield"/>
                </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

The only thing I added using Brackets were these lines:

```
                <columns
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Enter number of columns here"
                    name="./columns"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
```

---

Should a **dialog.xml** sync by Brackets from a path on CRXDE like this(apps/learning/components/UserCardInfo/dialog.xml)
be the same as returned by this URL http://localhost:4502/apps/learning/components/UserCardInfo/dialog.xml?

This is the dialog.xml sync by Brackets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <username
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            name="./userName"
            textLabel="Name"
            xtype="textfield"/>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

And this is the dialog.xml I see with the URL:

```
<dialog xmlns:MP="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.2/" 
        xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/" 
        xmlns:mix="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0" 
        xmlns:s7userdata="http://www.day.com/s7userdata/1.0/" 
        xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
        xmlns:DICOM="http://ns.adobe.com/DICOM/" 
        xmlns:xmpBJ="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/bj/" 
        xmlns:album="http://ns.adobe.com/album/1.0/" 
        xmlns:prismusagerights="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prismusagerights/2.1/" 
        xmlns:prl="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/prl/2.1/" 
        xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/" 
        xmlns:exifEX="http://cipa.jp/exif/1.0/" 
        xmlns:dex="http://ns.optimasc.com/dex/1.0/" 
        xmlns:xmpNote="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/note/" 
        xmlns:oak="http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/ns/1.0" 
        xmlns:stEvt="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#" 
        xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" 
        xmlns:idPriv="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/InDesign/private" 
        xmlns:slingevent="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/event/1.0" 
        xmlns:scg="http://www.adobe.com/social/scg/1.0" 
        xmlns:lr="http://ns.adobe.com/lightroom/1.0/" 
        xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" 
        xmlns:oauth="http://oauth.net/" 
        xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
        xmlns:stFNT="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/Font#" 
        xmlns:tiff="http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/" 
        xmlns:stMfs="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ManifestItem#" 
        xmlns:rep="internal" 
        xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/basic/2.1/" 
        xmlns:plus="http://ns.useplus.org/ldf/xmp/1.0/" 
        xmlns:Iptc4xmpExt="http://iptc.org/std/Iptc4xmpExt/2008-02-29/" 
        xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" 
        xmlns:psAux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/" 
        xmlns:xmpGImg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/" 
        xmlns:social="http://www.adobe.com/social/1.0" 
        xmlns:Iptc4xmpCore="http://iptc.org/std/Iptc4xmpCore/1.0/xmlns/" 
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
        xmlns:xmpG="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/" 
        xmlns:pdfx="http://ns.adobe.com/pdfx/1.3/" 
        xmlns:acdsee="http://ns.acdsee.com/iptc/1.0/" 
        xmlns:s7sitecatalyst="http://www.day.com/s7sitecatalyst/1.0/" 
        xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/" 
        xmlns:adobe_dam="http://www.adobe.com/adobe_dam/1.0" 
        xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" 
        xmlns:xmpDM="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/1.0/DynamicMedia/" 
        xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" 
        xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" 
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
        xmlns:xmpPLUS="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/PLUS/" 
        xmlns:crs="http://ns.adobe.com/camera-raw-settings/1.0/" 
        xmlns:vlt="http://www.day.com/jcr/vault/1.0" 
        xmlns:MicrosoftPhoto="http://ns.microsoft.com/photo/1.0" 
        xmlns:mediapro="http://ns.iview-multimedia.com/mediapro/1.0/" 
        xmlns:xmpTPg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/t/pg/" 
        xmlns:dam="http://www.day.com/dam/1.0" 
        xmlns:viewerpreset="http://www.day.com/viewerpreset/1.0/" 
        xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" 
        xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" 
        xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" 
        xmlns:crx="http://www.day.com/crx/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog" title="dialog" xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <username jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" name="./userName" textLabel="Name" xtype="textfield" />
    </items>
</dialog>
```

**Versions:**

AEM - 6.1

Brackets - Release 1.6 build 1.6.0-16680

AEM Brackets Extension - 0.0.13

Comment: is this issue only with dialogs? are you able to sync other files?

Comment: Only with dialog.xml

Comment: @awadheshv... the other files like: jsp, css, js, jpg syncs fine.

Comment: this is certainly strange. works fine for me. look for any error message, in brackets and aem. and you may want to report a bug here - https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Report-an-Issue

Comment: Which versions are you working with? (I update the post with mine...)

Comment: Brackets - 1.4 build 1.4.0-16380 (release 273804eb3); brackets extension - 0.0.13; aem 6.1 on java 1.8

Comment: @awadheshv, could take a look at my last update about the dialog from URL? Have your sync dialog.xml the <dialog> tag??

Comment: additional xml namespaces are not an issue. you can get the child nodes by dialog.infinity.json

Comment: Sure but, what about the <jcr:root> VS <dialog> ?

Comment: sorry I overlooked. I just checked again and on aem I am getting the dialog definition with a top level <Dialog> element. and in brackets its <jcr:root>, but my dialog definition is being exported to aem correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104858/discussion-between-awadheshv-and-nevitones).